# Initialization of a class array member in C++

Tags: c++

Using VS2012, I have encountered an unprecedented problem, my main class have a member, which is a an array of another small class.  This small class has an explicit constructor.  Now the problem: How to supply the initialization list?

The following is the code:

```
class A { //This is the small class
private:
    int value;
public:
    explicit A(int newNumber) {
        value = newNumber;
    }
};

class B {//This is the major class
private:
    A arrayOfA[5];
public:
    B() {//Compiler complain "no default constructor for class A"
         //But I really don't know how to supply the initialization list
    }
};
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a constructor initializer list:

```
B() : arrayOfA{A(1), A(2), A(3), A(4), A(5)} {}
```

I would also suggest changing the array to a `std::array`. If this is not C++11, I'm afraid you cannot initialize your member without having a default constructor for `A`. However, there is still the possibility of making your own (it's not hard) or using `boost::array`. In such a case, I am not sure whether it is possible to initialize the array directly, but it definitely is with a helper function.

Comment: +1 but I'm pretty sure VS2012 will not accept this. It *might* work if he has the CTP installed.

Comment: @Praetorian, I believe it will only work with the CTP, but then VS2013 is a better option anyway. That's a good point, though, which I guess makes the pre-C++11 advice more relevant. I can't remember whether VS2012 has `std::array`, or frankly whether it would work by using `({{A(1), ...}})` or something without the brace initialization syntax.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I learned this syntax in a C++ book I have bought, but wonder why it never worked.  Seems that It is not supported in VS2012.  In the end, I used the default constructor.  Maybe time to upgrade to VS2013.

Answer (score 2):

One way to resolve this is to provide a default constructor in `A`.

```
class A {
private:
    int value;
public:
    A() : value(0) {}

    explicit A(int newNumber) {
        value = newNumber;
    }
};
```

Comment: An alternative that avoids accidental implicit use of such a default constructor is to add a placeholder argument e.g. `enum Uninitialised { uninitialised }; A(Uninitialised) { }` - here I'm also avoiding the `value = 0` given the caller's intent to assign to the variable later....

Comment: Yes... that's an orthogonal design decision, but done as and for reasons it explains it the comment.  Sometimes it's useful to avoid initialisation - especially when creating a large array that you'll soon assign meaningful values to.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround for non-default-ctors not being useable here pre-C++11.

Just wrap your `arrayOfA` in an anonymous union. This means neither the constructors nor destructors will be called automatically. Use placement-new/delete. (Beware of automatically defined special member-functions though)

It would look like this:

```
class B {//This is the major class
private:
    union{A arrayOfA[5];};
public:
    B() {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof arrayOfA / sizeof *arrayOfA; i++)
            new((void*)&arrayOfA[i]) A(i);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you initialize all values of the array to 0 with a default constructor and then use a setter function that accepts 2 params to deal with manipulating the array:

```
A::setVal(int val)
{
    value = val;
}

B::setA(int index, int value)
{
    arrayOfA[index]->setVal(value);
}
```

Something like that should work.